# Visual Studio Windows Form Preview In Different Resolution?

Tags: visual-studio, editor, windows-forms-designer, screen-resolution

I enjoy running Visual Studio in 1680 x 1050 resolution.  However, our customers typically use 1024 x 768.  Is there some way I can keep my editor in the native resolution but display the form designer in a different one?  Thanks!

Austin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you get an additional monitor, configure it as a desktop extension at 1024 x 768, and use it as your UI development and testing screen.

Comment: agreed.  I have 3 monitors on my workstation.  1 widescreen, 2 fullscreen, I like looking at VS in 1280 x 1024 but our customers use crappy 1024 x 768 too, and sometimes they even use laptops.  So I have extra monitors.

Comment: Indeed. I use VS at 1920 x 1080, but "downgrade" to 1024 x 768 for UI design and testing all the time. You end up with really crappy UI designs if you don't. :-)

Comment: Cool.  That's what I was thinking as well.  I was just wondering if there was a cheaper solution :)

Answer (score 3):

I use a 2nd monitor at lower resolution when I need something like this.

Keep VS in your main window, then drag the form when running over to the other.

Also comes in handy when debugging, since you can see both your form and your step through at the same time.